# How to add support for all locale's currency symbols in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to show the user the currency symbol of their current locale. 
The locale and currency symbol can easily be retrieved with:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';    
var localeString = Localizations.localeOf(context).toString();
var _currencySymbol = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: localeString).currencySymbol;
```

The problem is that to retrieve the user's currency symbol the app has to support the user's locale. For eg. if you would like to show a user in South Africa a currency in South African Rands the `Locale('en', 'ZA')` has to be added to the current supported locales.

Adding support for all countries' locales in the supported locales list:

```
supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en', 'US'), // USD
    const Locale('en', 'ZA'), // ZAR
    const Locale('en', 'AU'), // AUD
    //..... All other locales
  ],
```

does not seem feasible and won't have support for new countries being added to the flutter intl list. Is there an easier/better way to add support for all countries' locales or to display all locales' currency symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The currency code** along with some other localization info is stored in a file called 
`number_symbols_data.dart` as a huge Map.

you can **import** the file from `Intl` library as follows:

```
import 'package:intl/number_symbols_data.dart';
```

then you can get the currency code by:

`numberFormatSymbols['ar_EG'].DEF_CURRENCY_CODE` .

**note:** replace `ar_EG` with the required local.

If you want to support **all Locales** you can use

```
supportedLocales: numberFormatSymbols.keys
      .where((key)=>key.toString().contains('_'))
      .map((key)=> key.toString().split('_'))
      .map((split)=>Locale(split[0],split[1])).toList(),
```

Edit: after careful investigation the previous code will only support locales which has `_<COUNTRY_CODE>` so to support other locals the code should be modified like so

```
supportedLocales: numberFormatSymbols.keys
          //.where((key)=>key.toString().contains('_'))
          .map((key)=> key.toString().split('_'))
          .map((split)=>Locale(split[0],split.length == 1? null:split[1])).toList(),
```

Comment: To get the required locale with `Localizations.localeOf(context)` the flutter app needs to support that locale, which brings me back to my initial question, how do I support all the locales in my flutter app?

Comment: Unfortunately `Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()` returns only "en" instead of "en_US" if you use `supportedLocales: numberFormatSymbols.keys.map((key)=>Locale(key)).toList()`.  This means the $ sign is always returned as the currency symbol of the locale.

Comment: The reason for the "en" return was because "en" was included in the locale list together with "en_US", "en_AU", "en_ZA", etc. This caused the locale to default to "en" instead of "en_AU", if "en" is removed from the `numberFormatSymbols.keys` map the correct "en_XX" locale is returned.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work perfectly as the values returned by `numberFormatSymbols.keys.map((key)=>Locale(key)).toList()` is without a country code. `Locale('en', 'AU')` provides more information than `Locale("en_AU")`. I need all country codes, not language codes, if that makes sense.

Comment: @PetriOosthuizen Thank you for spotting that ,I filtered the locales and now it is working as expected, please ,recheck the answer after correction

Comment: @PetriOosthuizen don't forget .toList() Like me :) I just added now